# How to view the current location in google map using longitude and latitude of that location in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps

I have read the longitude & latitude of the current location in obj-c. Now, how can I view the current location in the Google map, using that locations's longitude and latitude?

Can anyone give me some example code which helps me to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use  longitude & latitude of the current location to show user location.
The following line will do so.

```
mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the method you can use with the map view:

```
 [googleMap setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, coordSpan];
```

googleMap will be you MKMapView object and the location would be a CLLocationCoordinate2D (The lat. & lon. values) struct and coordSpan would be a MKCoordinateSpan struct (Specifies how large the viewing area is).

Update: This can be used for custom latitude and longitude valuesThe suggestion of using

```
mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

Would be the easiest direct way if your just concerned with the users exact location.

Comment: I assume your using interface builder. So in your view add a MKMapView object, then create a connection to an IBOutlet in your view controller class. In the example above you could make it IBOutlet MKMapView *googleMap; Once the connection is made you can use the method up above.