# How will get current location in iphone

Tags: iphone, mapkit

I am making google map integration in iphone. I have to show current location showing in map. How will i get current location ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [[[mapview userLocation] location] coordinate];  
NSLog(@"Location found from Map: %f %f",location.latitude,location.longitude);
```

Comment: One detail: this will work if and only if mapview was(is) visible.

Comment: It's returning 0,0 even tho i'm in completly different place ;)

Answer (score 3):

Search for `Accessing the Device’s Current Location` in following article:

- [MKMapView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html)

  - [showsUserLocation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapView/showsUserLocation) (`MapView.showsUserLocation = YES;`)
  - [userLocationVisible](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapView/userLocationVisible)
  - [userLocation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapView/userLocation)

Related SO posts:

- [iPhone current user location coordinates showing as (0,0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449486/iphone-current-user-location-coordinates-showing-as-0-0)
- [How to view the current location in google map using longitude and latitude of that location in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018332/how-to-view-the-current-location-in-google-map-using-longitute-n-latitude-of-that)

Answer (score 3):

I think the question has been answered -

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [[[mapview userLocation] location] coordinate];  
NSLog(@"Location found from Map: %f %f",location.latitude,location.longitude);
```

place this in the `viewdidappear:animated`

then you should find that you have the right location. Doing it any sooner and the location won't be set yet and you'll probably end up in the ocean :)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is to write code like `mapview.showsUserLocation = YES;`, where mapview is your UIMapView class object.

Comment: No any above code is working well. These all are redirecting to same place an dthat place are not belongs to my place.